# IllegalStateException:Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process typroject. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: java, android, firebase

app is crashing on clicking the register button

this is my registerActivity:

```
package com.example.typroject;

public class registerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference mRootref;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        mRootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String txtUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String txtName = name.getText().toString();
                String txtemail = email.getText().toString();
                String txtpassword = password.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(txtUsername) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txtName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txtemail) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txtpassword)){
                    Toast.makeText(registerActivity.this, "Empty Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (txtpassword.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(registerActivity.this, "Password is too Short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    registeruser(txtUsername, txtName , txtemail , txtpassword );
//                    startActivity(new Intent(registerActivity.this , MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                }

            }


        });
    }


    private void registeruser(String Username, String Name, String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                HashMap<String , Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("username" , username);
                map.put("name" , name);
                map.put("email" , email);
                map.put("password" , password);
                map.put("id" , mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                mRootref.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(registerActivity.this , MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(registerActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my module app Dependencies :
dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
```

}

last four dependencies i have added by my own
and i am a newb and its my first proper android project help me out
i had seen this code from an youtuber  and tried to do the same but for my own project but i guess the versions that youtuber used are outdated and i need to used the latest ones

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)` before using any `Firebase` api.

Example:

```kotlin
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    // other things...
}
```

My suggestion would be to initialise Firebase in `Application` class.

Comment: nope its not working app is still crashing once clicking on register button